# Validate a number with regex

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, validation, input

I have a WPF form where the user is able to enter width and height to scale an image. I want to validate the number with a regular expression. The user should be able to enter only number greater than zero.

At the moment I use the PreviewTextInput event

```
<TextBox Name="Height" Width="50" PreviewTextInput="Height_ValidateNumber"></TextBox>
```

and check the input with this method

```
    private void Height_ValidateNumber(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^[1-9][0-9]*$");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
```

---

The regex I use is `^[1-9][0-9]\*$`

The problem with this is that I'm actully able to enter everything but no digits except zero...

If I am using `[^1-9][0-9]\*$` I am able to enter all digits except zero...

I think that the regex `^[1-9][0-9]\*$` is not wrong. I think it is another problem.

Comment: Why is it "wrong"? What doesn't work? Please be clear

Comment: I guess you need `e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);`

Comment: What range do you want the number to be? 1 to 100? 10 to 999?

Comment: @sshashank124 sry forgot about it edited!

Comment: @zx81 as i described I want all numbers greater than 0

Comment: Gerret, I saw that. I was just wondering if when validating, you might want to reject width and height values that make no sense, such as `99999999999`, hence the question. It's a different regex task if you have a range.

Comment: Please do not extend your question by repeating the same thing over and over. Be more speciffic instead. Also, just use `TryParse` method and work on integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're filtering all the valid values instead of invalid

Change this

```
e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
```

to

```
e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
```

Update1 : `e.Text` gives newly entered text, you can concatenate `TextBox.Text` with `e.Text` to frame full text.

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox) sender;
Regex regex = new Regex("^[1-9][0-9]*$");
e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(tb.Text + e.Text);
```

Comment: Yea, but I mainly have to problem that I can not enter a zero also after I have entered any digit.

Comment: @Gerret What do you mean by that? You mean `50` is invalid number?

Comment: Yes, 50 should be a valid number. Everything greater than 0 should be a valid number. But if I use my regex I am not able to enter a zero and I do not know why...

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not know that I only get the changed Text it is working now :D

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a RegExpr, but why dont you use:

```
long number;
if (UInt32.TryParse(e.Text, out number)) 
    // You can use ANY .net Number class here 
    //(you want > 0, use the UInt16,UInt32,UInt64 Structs)
```

Seems easier and more logical to me :)